# How to replace a text with value case insensitively in PowerShell (dot) .contain() method

Tags: powershell, dictionary, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to replace the text case insensitively with Dictionary value.

Here is my dictionary looks like,

```
Key             Value
-------         ------
Environment     Test
FILETYPE        All
IsEncrypted     Yes
```

I'm working on this powershell script,

# The text values are stored in the variable called $templatestrings. Following is output of the $templatestrings are

environment, filetype, IsEncrypted

```
    if($Dictionary.ContainsKey($string))
    {
        $templatecontent = $templatecontent -ireplace "{{$string}}", ($Dictionary[$string])
    }
$templatecontent | set-content $destinationfilename
```

Even though I have added "i" in the replace command, this script is working in case sensitive mode. it is not able to replace the text with dictionary values.. Can someone please suggest me how can i convert this into case insensitive.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PowerShell is case insensitive by default - try this `$d = @{}; $d["A"] = 1; $d.ContainsKey("a"); $d["a"]` - it reports that the dictionary does contain the key and finds the value for it, even when the case is different.  Can you post some example content of the templatecontent? Reading with Get-Content will return a string array, and using -replace on an array will work nicely in PSv4, but if you are really on PSv2 like your tag says, it might not work for that reason. Which version of PS are you actually using?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, Thanks for the reply.
Following 3 are the contents of strings==>`environment, filetype, IsEncrypted`
and I'm using PSv2.

Comment: OK, I cannot see anything wrong. Are there any spaces anywhere? Try `foreach ($string in $templatestrings) { $string = $string.Trim() ...` at the start of that loop to get rid of any leading/trailing spaces. Or try `if ($Dictionary.ContainsKey($string)) { write-host "String $string found!" } ...` at the start of that loop and and see if it enters the loop at all. Then in that loop, try `if ($templatecontent -match "{{$string}}"){write-host "matched $string"}  ... ` to see if you can identify how far it gets / which bit is failing.

Comment: There are no spaces. And you are right, I don't see any bit/string in the loop. I think ~.contain ~ method is case sensitive by default.

Comment: We don't see how your dictionary is initialized. Please provide a small but complete example that does not work. Also provide its output and any errors it prints (or mention that it completes without errors).

Comment: One thing that might help: `[Dictionary[String,String]]::new([StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`